# New thread is running as UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface

I have a form "DisplayImagesForm" which calls a function `loadImages()` in the constructor:

```
public ImageScraperForm(string query, RichTextBox textBox)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.query = query;
    loadImages();
}
```

Then the `loadImages()` function creates a new thread at the end:

```
{
   ...
   Thread thread = new Thread(readNextImage);
   thread.Start();
}
```

The problem is that the thread doesn't seem to be running as a different thread than UI thread. The `readNextImage()` method loads images from a server which takes some times - while loading the image it blocks the whole form. It's not normal, because the "thread" should be running separately from the UI thread. Also the `readNextImage()` function can modify the UI elements without `Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate` - no exception is thrown.

Comment: It's really difficult to get interactive results back from a `Thread`. There are much easier ways to do that, but we need to know what `readNextImage` does. Does it do File or network I/O? You should use `await`. Does it do heavy computation or procedural generation? You may be better off using a [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: It's "Windows Form". readNextImage does network I/O. There is no heavy computation, it just download image as stream and display in picture box.

Comment: Did you try to make a timer and if that timer goes off before the thread terminates, it sends you a console message such as "did not finish" so that you'll know that the thread is working but the work my cost more than you'd think. I'd considered using the perfmon app while your program is executing to see how many ressources are allocated while your thread is doing I/O work !

Answer (score -2):

If you're trying to download an image over the internet and display it in a WinForm control; you're going about it completely wrong.

Do not do any lengthy processing in your Form constructor; that is going to make your form unresponsive. If you are going to display something in the UI you should do that in your Form's Paint event handler. If you are trying to download something over the internet you should be using `await`, not a `Thread`. Threads use a CPU core and, since the internet is orders of magnitude slower than a CPU, you are going to be blocking it immediately.

The correct way of doing this is using `await` to load the file when you need it. If you need it when you start the `Load` event handler is a good choice.

```
private async void YourForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var c = new HttpClient())
    using (var resp = await c.GetAsync(@"http://uri/to/image.jpg"))
    using (var content = resp.Content)
    using (var s = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        _img = new Bitmap(s);
    }

    YourControl.Invalidate();
}

private void YourForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (_img != null)
        DrawToYourControl(_img);
}
```

Comment: Even that is doing it wrong, you are re-downloading the content every paint event. The paint handler is not the place to do this, If I had to choose I would do it in the `Loaded` event.

Comment: _img will not equal null the next paint event.

Comment: Ok, I missed that, but still, the paint event? There is no reason for that to be in this event. You never use `PaintEventArgs` which is the only reason to be inside the event. If you had done `DoSomethingWith(_img, e);` I could agree, but DoSomethingWith does not use the arg either.

Comment: Lastly, you can not safely do a async paint event, the `PaintEventArgs` [are inside a `using` statement](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,13387), so when your await returns `e` will be disposed (if you used `e`)

Comment: My example did not use `PaintEventArgs` but you're right, if it did that would not work. I changed it to use `Load` as you suggested.